# Difference between probabilistic and randomized algorithm

Tags: algorithms

What I understated is this:

Probabilistic algorithm: an algorithm that produces result in determined time with a `confidence` value about the probability of the produced result being correct.

Randomized algorithm: an algorithm that uses some sort of randomization to reach the result, that too with absolute surety of reaching the correct result.

Is this correct? And what exactly is the difference between these two?